# Shopify Variant Is Not Selected After JS action

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

Using funnel builder app for Shopify. Got 1 native shopify select item that's choosing variants, 2 other static input methods that I added (radio buttons and input), and JS that pulls input values from these 2 and sets select to it. The problem is- on the front end, it changes select value, but when I add to cart, it's still adding default option.

The select html looks like this.

```
<select class="form-control variant_Quantity" onchange="change_product_variant(this);" id="select_61">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option> 
</select>
```

And this is my jQuery

```
$(".pricelinewrap").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){    
        $(this).find("input[type=radio]").prop('checked', 'checked');
        var quanval =  $(this).find("input[type=radio]").prop('checked', 'checked').val();
        $("input[name='quantity']").val(quanval);
        $("select#select_62").val(quanval);
    });
});

$("input[name='quantity']").change(function(){
    var newquanval = $(this).val();
    $("select#select_62").val(newquanval);
});
```

Keep in mind- everything works on the front end. But looks like i'm missing something that the actual variant is not selected. However, select option is shown correctly, when something else is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger `change` event to the select, since the following code:

```
$("input[name='quantity']").val(quanval);
$("select#select_62").val(quanval);
```

only changes the value of the select but it doesn't fire the actual `change` event.

It should become like this:

```
$("input[name='quantity']").val(quanval).trigger('change');
$("select#select_62").val(quanval).trigger('change');
```